# Automatic update of entity every day

Tags: symfony, datetime, events, doctrine, entity

I'm creating my portfolio with Symfony 3 and I want to show my skills with my experience.

I have a "Skill" entity with a "startAt" param (type=datetime) and a "exp" param (string).

The "exp" param = the difference between "startAt" and the current date.

I add some lifecycle callback so the "exp" param update every time I touch my "Skill" entity but here is my question:

**How can I update my entity every day without touching it?**

For exemple right now I have "exp = 6 months" but next month this param need to be "7 months".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since "startAt" is likely mapped to a field name in the database called "start_at", this date is all the data you need to set and store.  The method in the entity called getExp(), which maps to the variable "exp" would then take $this->startAt() value and calculate the difference between that start at time and the current time.  You can use the PHP DateTime object to calculate the difference in units of days, months or years, depending on your preference.

Also, "exp" doesn't need to be a field you need to store or map to the database because it can easily be calculated on the fly based on the "startAt" date value anyway.

Comment: This is how it works right now : I have method get/setExp() in my Entity and an other mehtod "calcExp" with lifecycle callback (PrePersist and PerUpdate). The method do a "date_diff" between "$this->getStartAt()" and "new \Datetime", then I create my string "1 year", "2 months", 1 month",...and set the string in "exp". It works, but only in "PreUpdate / PrePersist, I'd like to use it even if I don't touch the Entity :/ Hope it's clear enough ^^

Comment: @MickaelLeger You're missing the whole point of this answer. You don't need to store `exp` in your entity, just `startAt`. Your current `getExp` method could just calculate the string and return it, without ever saving it to a database (and also getting rid of `setExp`). Eg: `public function getExp() { return $this->getStartAt()->diff(new \DateTime(), true); }` no storing required.

Comment: Ok I understand what you mean : I deleted my param "exp", my methods "setExp" and "calcExp" and I just put my "calcExp" code in my getExp. I think it works, I will see next months if the data update but it should :) Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

create a command that update your entity and make a cron tab with it

Comment: I didn't know the cron tab, I will take a look !